# Python decimal to hex conversion in binary

Tags: python, io, binary, hex

Recently, I have been studying Python and had a question on my mind to ask.

I am wondering why x= 2998302 is stored as 02 2D C0 1E instead of 2D C0 1E? **I think it is because x.to_bytes(4, 'big)**. Even though this is the case, my calculator translates 2998302 to 2DC01E. So I don't understand where we get 02 in the beginning. If I also add 02 and calculate 02DC01E, my computer gives another result.

Here's the code I have

```
    # with open("binary", 'bw') as bin_file:
#     bin_file.write(bytes(range(17)))
#
# with open("binary", 'br') as binFile:
#     for b in binFile:
#         print(b)

a = 65534       # FF FE
b = 65535       # FF FF
c = 65536       # 00 01 00 00
x = 2998302     # 02 2D C0 1E

with open("binary2", 'bw') as bin_file:
    bin_file.write(a.to_bytes(2, 'big'))
    bin_file.write(b.to_bytes(2, 'big'))
    bin_file.write(c.to_bytes(4, 'big'))
    bin_file.write(x.to_bytes(4, 'big'))
    bin_file.write(x.to_bytes(4, 'little'))

with open("binary2", 'br') as bin_file:
    e = int.from_bytes(bin_file.read(2), 'big')
    print(e)
    f = int.from_bytes(bin_file.read(2), 'big')
    print(f)
    g = int.from_bytes(bin_file.read(4), 'big')
    print(g)
    h = int.from_bytes(bin_file.read(4), 'big')
    print(h)
    i = int.from_bytes(bin_file.read(4), 'big')
    print(i)
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you believe that it is being stored as 02 2D C0 1E? The value in hex is 002DC01E.

Comment: The contents of the file "binary2" is `FF FE FF FF 00 01 00 00 00 2D C0 1E 1E C0 2D 00`, So, where do you see `02 2D C0 1E`?

Comment: Hello, I am watching a tutorial on Udemy and the teacher commented it out this way, which made me think it is 002DC01E.